# Storing 15,000 items in Java

Tags: java, arrays, spreadsheet

I have a document with 15,000 items.  Each item contains 6 variables (strings and integers).  I have to copy all of these into some sort of two dimensional array, what the best way to do it?

Here are my ideas so far:

```
Make a GIANT 2D array or array list the same way you make any other array.
```

**Pros**: Simple **Cons**: Messy(would create a class just for this), huge amount of code, if I make a mistake it will be imposable to find where it is, all variables would have to be string even the ints which will make my job harder down the road

```
Make a new class with a super that takes in all the variables I need.
Create each item as a new instance of this class.
Add all of the instances to a 2D array or array list.
```

**Pros**: Simple, less messy, easier to find a mistake, not all the variables need to be strings which makes it much easier later when I don't have to convert string to int, a little less typing for me **Cons**: Slower?  Will instances make my array compile slower?  And will they make the over all array slow when I'm searching to items in it?

These ideas don't seem all to great :( and before I start the three week, five hour a day process of adding these items I would like to find the best way so I won't have to do it again... Suggestions on my current ideas or any new ideas?

Data example:

```
0: 100, west, sports, 10.89, MA, united
```

**not actual data*

Comment: What do you need those variables for? If you are going to do some lookups later, I would suggest database instead.

Comment: Why do you need a two-dimensional array? What are the two dimensions? What do you mean by "new class with a super"? What do you mean by "compiling" your array? It's very hard to tell what you're really talking about here, but it definitely sounds like you should have a class to encapsulate related items.

Comment: _three week, five hour a day process of adding these items_ `:O`

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of 2D array. It's not clear in your question.

Comment: Give as an example how your data looks like.

Comment: I gave an example of what my data looks like

Comment: Why is making a class to hold your attributes "messy"?

Answer (score 1):

Your second options seems to be good. You can create a class containing all the items and create an array of that class.

You may use the following:
1. Read the document using buffered reader, so that memory issues will not occur.
2. Create a class containing your items.
3. Create a List of type you need and store the elements into it.

Let me know in case you face further problems.

Comment: Why would I want to persist the data, but also about 100-150k words/ numbers is what like not even a gigabyte right?

Comment: So you can use a list of objects to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the document with the 15000 * 6 items, in my experience you would be better served writing a program to use regex and parse it and have the output be the contents of the java array in the format you want. With such a parsing program in place, it will then also be very easy for you to change the format of the 15000 lines if you want to generate it differently.

As to the final format, I would have an ArrayList of your bean. By you text thus far, you don't necessarily need a super that takes in the variables, unless you need to have subtypes that are differentiated.

You'll probably run out of static space in a single class. So what I do is break up a big class like that into a file with a bunch of inner nested classes that each have a 64K (or less) part of the data as static final arrays, and then I merge them together in the main class in that file.

I have this in a class of many names to fix:

```
class FixName{

    static String[][] testStrings;
    static int add(String[][] aTestStrings, int lastIndex){
        for(int i=0; i<aTestStrings.length; ++i) {
            testStrings[++lastIndex]=aTestStrings[i];
        }
        return lastIndex;
    }
    static {
        testStrings = new String[
                FixName1.testStrings.length
                +FixName2.testStrings.length
                +FixName3.testStrings.length
                +FixName4.testStrings.length
/**/        ][];
        int lastIndex=-1;
        lastIndex=add(FixName1.testStrings,lastIndex);
        lastIndex=add(FixName2.testStrings,lastIndex);
        lastIndex=add(FixName3.testStrings,lastIndex);
        lastIndex=add(FixName4.testStrings,lastIndex);
/**/    }
}
class FixName1 {
static String[][] testStrings = {
{"key1","name1","other1"},
{"key2","name2","other2"},
//...
{"keyN","nameN","otherN"}
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper (Item) if you have not already(as your question does not state it clearly).

If the size of the elements is fixed ie 1500 use array other wise use LinkedList(write your own linked list or use Collection).

If there are others operations that you need to support on this collection of items, may be further inserts, search( in particular) use balanced binary search tree.

With the understanding of the question i would say linked list is better option.

Answer (score 0):

If the items have a unique property (name or id or row number or any other unique identifier) I recommend using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with a wrapper around the item. If you are going to do any kind of lookup on your data (find item with id x and do operation y) this is the fastest option and is also very clean, it just requires a wrapper and you can use a datastructure that is already implemented.

If you are not doing any lookups and need to process the items en masse in no specific order I would recommend an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it is very optimized as it is the most commonly used collection in java. You would still need the wrapper to keep things clean and a list is far cleaner than an array at almost no extra cost.

Little point in making your own collection as your needs are not extremely specific, just use one that is already implemented and never worry about your code breaking, if it does it is oracles fault ;)